# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement paddlepaddle (from versions: none) No matching distribution found for paddlepaddle

Tags: python

I've been trying to install paddlepaddle from both Pycharm and from the power shell as suggested using:

> pip install paddlepaddle -i https://mirror.baidu.com/pypi/simple

but I'm getting the following error for them:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement paddlepaddle (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for paddlepaddle

How can I fix these and install properly?

Comment: Can't reproduce. It is working for me (starting from a new empty virtual environment, with Python 3.8.10). This results in installing `paddlepaddle==2.2.0` plus various dependencies.

Comment: I have the same problem, running ubuntu 20.04 in WSL1, python version is 3.10.2. The documentation is old but talks about python 3.5 through 3.8. I managed to install it in an environment running python 3.9; not that it's useful as my project has some 3.10 dependancies

Comment: try using python -m pip install paddlepaddle==2.2.2 -i https://mirror.baidu.com/pypi/simple

Comment: `pip install --upgrade pip` solved the issue for me

Comment: Check your python version. paddlepaddle support python version 3.6/3.7/3.8/3.9/3.10. [ref](https://www.paddlepaddle.org.cn/install/quick?docurl=/documentation/docs/zh/install/pip/windows-pip.html)

Answer (score 1):

The issue for me was due to having python version 3.11. After uninstalling that version and installing version 3.9, the error went away.

Instead of uninstalling other python version, you should be able to just install python 3.9 and then change the default python version by updating your System Environment Variable -> Path. Need to add 2 paths. For example something like this:

1. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64\Scripts  or C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts   (for pip)  and
2. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python39_64  (for python)